# php web server can not read php files

Tags: php

i want to use this web server in php

```
set_time_limit(0);

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 80;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

echo "\n Listening On port $port For Connection... \n\n";

while(1)
{
    socket_listen($sock);

    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);

    $incoming = array();
    $incoming = explode("\r\n", $input);

    $fetchArray = array();
    $fetchArray = explode(" ", $incoming[0]);

    $file = $fetchArray[1];
    if($file == "/"){ 
        $file = "index.php"; 
    } else {
        $filearray = array();
        $filearray = explode("/", $file);

        $file = $filearray[1];
    }
echo $fetchArray[0] . " Request " . $file . "\n"; 

$output = "";

$Header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n" .
"Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT \r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html \r\n\r\n";

$Content = file_get_contents($file);

$output = $Header . $Content;

    socket_write($client,$output,strlen($output));
    socket_close($client);
```

and in my index.php is echo function to write a string or other functions but this web server can not run that echo or other php functions and in my localhost i see full withe page and this is my problem where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this error (one of which for example that your web server has not read permissions and thus cannot open the .php files). You could try [enabling the php logs and setting your preffered locations](https://www2.suresupport.com/faq.php/14/412) and read the error that prevents your code from being displayed.

Comment: there is no permission error . index.php run true on console but can not run on localhost on browser

Comment: @user3748360 this is not true. On your console the user is you, while when it comes for the webserver the user is apache. Obviously you can r/w/x the file, but is apache able to? What are the permissions of your file? Have you granted ownership of these files to apache?

Comment: @sestus The server that the asker is using is not apache.

Comment: @Jim yes you are right. I just gave an example, and apache is one mainstream ,so it just came out. I wanted to show the principle. Anyways my proposed  way of troubleshooting this is checking the php logs.